# Using Spring @Transactional propagations in JTA

Tags: spring, jpa, websphere, jta

I am trying to implement Client Orchestration Strategy([ibm-client-orchestration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts4/index.html?ca=dat-)) due to our system arhitecture. We use an integration layer which in fact orchestrates some web services. A call to a web services is made in a single unit of work and delegates to a business layer which uses Spring framework. An example would be something like this:

```
UserTransaction ut = getUserTransaction()
ut.begin();
// insert data, will be delegated to some jpa repository
service1.saveData(data)
// find data inserted above
service2.findData(data)
ut.commit();
```

In the mentioned link, the author suggest to use propagation MANDATORY on save and propagation SUPPORTS on finding, which will try to find data in a transaction log. Somehow, I do not know I am not able to find the inserted data in the find step given the above scenario. Here are some useful information that may help:

1. we use Websphere 8.5. Our datasouce is comming from Websphere, is configured as XA datasource and it's taken from JNDI.
2. Platform transaction manager from Spring is configured as JtaTransactionManager
3. Entity Manger Factory is taken from a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and uses a Hibernate JPA Vendor with the following properties:

   jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
               environment.getRequiredProperty("entitymanagerfactory.hibernate.hbm2ddl.production"));
       jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");
       jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform");
       jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup");
4. I didn't configured any JPA Provider in Websphere, so it should be it's default implementation.

I mention that if I use in the delegation DAO layer, the saveAndFlush() method from the jpa repository, I am able to find if, but I would preffer not to use it and use the transaction propagation.

Definition for transactionManager bean:

```
    @Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JtaTransactionManager txManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    txManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return txManager;
}
    @Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    // hibernate vendor
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(databaseType());
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    // compose entityManager

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setDataSource(datasource());
    factoryBean.setJtaDataSource(datasource());
    // scan packages
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty("entitymanager.scan.packages"));

    // JPA properties
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(getEntityManagerFactoryJpaProperties());

    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should spring handle the lifecycle, you shouldn't call `afterPropertiesSet` yourself, spring will do this for you. The same with `getObject()`, you should be simply returning the `FactoryBean` so that spring can properly manage it.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should be using the websphre specific `JtaTransactionManager` instead of the generic one. I would suggest using the `tag which detects which specific or generic one to use. So basically replace your definition of the`JtaTransactionManager` with the following:

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

Next your code isn't using springs transaction management but plain JTA transactions either use annotations to drive the transaction (`@Transactional` with `<tx:annotation-driven />` or use an injected `PlatformTransactionManager` to start and commit transactions.

```
TransactionStatus txStatus = getTransactionManager().getTransaction(null);
// insert data, will be delegated to some jpa repository
service1.saveData(data)
// find data inserted above
service2.findData(data)
getTransactionManager().commit(txStatus);
```

Also see [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) for another approach and more information.

In the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` make sure the inject the `jtaDataSource` property instead of the `dataSource` property, this will trigger some additional settings.

```
@Bean
public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lcemfb.setJtaDataSource(dataSource());
    // .... Other properties
    return lcemfb;
}
```

Another note on your hibernate configuration, the `hibernate.connection.*` properties are useless due to the injection of the datasource and you don't need the `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` as that is (or at least should) already be covered by the configured `JtaPlatform`.

Comment: I added a comment with how it's configures transactionManager and entityManagerFactory. I would say that it's the same as you mentioned. I'm not sure if we have the posibility to get the transaction manger in our integration layer as this layer has nothing to do with spring framework. Thanks for your answer. I will try, maybe a service locator approach to get the transaction manager from spring. If you have another ideas ..

Comment: No it isn't.. YOu are using the `JtaTransactionManager` and not the websphere specific one. The namespace detects which version to use. Also your LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is configured wrong, you should set either the `dataSource` or `jtaDataSource` property, not both. In regard to the transaction-manager I was under the impression that the code was Spring managed, if it isn't ignore that part.